# How to download a picture from the site?

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I am trying to make a parser based on "AngleSharp".
I use the following code for download:

```
var itemsAttr = document.QuerySelectorAll("img[id='print_user_photo']"); 
string foto_url = itemsAttr[0].GetAttribute("src");
string path = pathFolderIMG + id_source + ".jpg";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
webClient.DownloadFile(foto_url, path);
```

For pages "type_1" -[**link**](https://rabota.by/resume/view/528089/) -  the code works.
For pages "type_2" - [**link**](https://rabota.by/resume/view/527165/) - the code does not work.

How to download photos for pages "type_2"?

Comment: "the code does not work" is not helpful. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include ... a specific problem or error ... in the question itself."*

Answer (score 3):

Please read the AngleSharp documentation carefully, e.g., looking at the [FAQ](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp/blob/master/doc/Questions.md) we get:

```
var imageUrl = @"https://via.placeholder.com/150";
var localPath = @"g:\downloads\image.jpg";
var download = context.GetService<IDocumentLoader>().FetchAsync(new DocumentRequest(new Url(imageUrl)));

using (var response = await download.Task)
{
    using (var target = File.OpenWrite(localPath))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(target);
    }
}
```

where we used a configuration like

```
var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader(new LoaderOptions { IsResourceLoadingEnabled = true }).WithCookies();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
```

Comment: I get errors:

**1.** `Could not find the type or name of the namespace "LoaderOptions" (perhaps there is no using directive or a link to the assembly).`

**2.** `'IBrowsingContext "does not contain a definition for" GetService "and could not find the extension method" GetService ", which takes the type" IBrowsingContext "as the first argument (it is possible that the using directive or the link to the assembly is missing).`

Could you tell me how to eliminate them? **Picture link** - [**link**](https://prnt.sc/m3xrus)

Comment: Which version of AngleSharp are you using? Use the latest - AngleSharp 0.10.1.